# Add JavaScript-Library “Fitty” to WordPress

Tags: javascript, library

I am a beginner of Wordpress with a small programming knoledge. I managed to integrate the fitty-script succsesfully to my Wordpress installation and yes, it works. But only as long as i am logged in as admin in wordpress. Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be. Thanks in advance for your support.Please find below the code:

```
function child_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'fitty', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/fitty.min.js' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/fitty.min.js' ) ), true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'child', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/child.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/child.js' ) ), true );

    }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_scripts' );
```

The code is placed in functions.php of a child theme (impreza).
As I am not a developer I don't know how to inspect if the script will be displayed in the source code. I am sorry.

Thanks @Rup. I inspected the site as described, but unfortunately the search of "fitty" gives me no result. What does it mean?

Comment: What hook did you use? Paste your code, please.

Comment: That looks ok, nothing in what you posted above relates to whether or not the user is logged in.  Wondering if there's another condition somewhere in a template that checks the logged in condition before executing something and that's somehow preventing your script from executing.  Question:  If you're not logged in can you still see the script enqueued in the source code using developer tools?  Let's make sure it's there first.

Comment: where is this code placed exactly?

Comment: On your web page right click, 'View Page Source' or similar, then ctrl+F search for 'fitty'.